# Bson ObjectId generating same value in python dataclass objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, bson, objectid

I am trying to generate an ObjectId that is unique for objects I make from a dataclass. Hovewer for every object I make from my class, it generates the same Id.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from bson import ObjectId

@dataclass
class B:
    id: ObjectId=ObjectId()

b =B()
b.id
>>ObjectId('600c9d09c889e41a182988b0')

c =B()
c.id
>>ObjectId('600c9d09c889e41a182988b0')
```

I do not understand this behaviour, is it due to the dataclass keeping the same default  objectId reference everytime it inits the class?

Do you have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the above  dataclass would be initiated as:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, x: ObjectId = ObjectId()):
        self.id=x
```

The default value for the class would always be the static `ObjectId` generated when the class is loaded.
In the end, I suppose dynamic values should not be passed as init params.

The correct way would be to use `__post_init__`:

```
from dataclasses import field

@dataclass
class B:
    id: ObjectId = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.id = ObjectId()

b =B()
b.id
>>ObjectId('60104262ee527a385cb44a11')

c =B()
c.id
>>ObjectId('6010426bee527a385cb44a12')
```